# R Cross Validation

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm doing cross validation. So I wanted to split data into 10 folds. Somebody has post following code.

```
f_K_fold <- function(Nobs,K=10){
    rs <- runif(Nobs)
    id <- seq(Nobs)[order(rs)]
    k <- as.integer(Nobs * seq(1, K-1) / K)
    k <- matrix(c(0, rep(k, each=2), Nobs), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    k[,1] <- k[,1]+1
    l <- lapply(seq.int(K), function(x, k, d)
        list(train=d[!(seq(d) %in% seq(k[x, 1],k[x, 2]))],
             test=d[seq(k[x,1],k[x,2])]),
        k=k,d=id)
    return(l)
}
```

however I don't really understand what the `lapply` doing. Could someone explain to a newbie? Appreciate it.

Comment: What is it that you do not understand? Simply stating that you do not understand is not really helpful for us.

Comment: In addition, I agree with @Roman that a bit of indentation and code formatting would really improve the readability. I edited the code to show you how I would format the code. I also added some spaces in the code, that makes the code less of a visual block, and more readable.

Answer (score 3):

It's really unfortunate that the code folding in this example is horrible, since aving properly formatted code can aid in understanding the code and catching mistakes.

The last three lines can be viewed as an anonymous function passed to `lapply`. `lapply` in essence "climbs" a list and for each list element, applies that (anonymous) function. In the example below, I've disambiguated the lines into a not so anonymous function and a call to `lapply`.

```
  notSoanonymousFunction <- function(x, k, d) {
    list(train = d[!(seq(d) %in% seq(k[x,1],k[x,2]))],
         test = d[seq(k[x,1],k[x,2])])
  }
  l <- lapply(seq.int(K), FUN = notSoanonymousFunction, k = k, d = id)
```

If you look at `?lapply`, you'll notice that there are no `k` or `d` arguments. However, these arguments do belong to our `notSoanonymousFunction`, and `lapply` takes it in via the `...` argument.

As a mental exercise for you, I will show you one more trick how to learn what the function is doing. If you need to see what is happening inside the function, place a `browser()` call inside and run it. In your case, this would look like this:

```
  notSoanonymousFunction <- function(x, k, d) {
    browser()
    list(train = d[!(seq(d) %in% seq(k[x,1],k[x,2]))],
         test = d[seq(k[x,1],k[x,2])])
  }
```

Once you run this, your console should say something along the lines of

```
Browser[1] >
```

You are now effectively inside the function. You can navigate to next line by typing `n`, running the whole chunk by `c` and quitting the browser all together, by pressing `Q` (see `?browser()`).  You can view and manipulate objects ad libidum. You can try by checking your workspace with `ls()` to see which objects are inside the function. You can bet your family farm that there will be objects `x`, `k` and `d`.